# can not show view on top of status bar, uiwindow, objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwindow

I am trying to put an overlay on top of status bar by doing the following :

ViewController implementation

```
- (IBAction)addViewOnTop:(id)sender {
    StatusBarOverlayWindow *overlay = [[ACStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    overlay.hidden = NO;
    [overlay makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

StatusBarOverlayWindow header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StatusBarOverlayWindow : UIWindow {
}
@end
```

StatusBarOverLayWindow implementation

```
@implementation StatusBarOverlayWindow
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Place the window on the correct level and position
        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
        self.frame = frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

When I click a button, nothing happens at all.
Does anyone have any thoughts about this issue. Please guide, thanks

Comment: Try keeping a strong reference to the `StatusBarOverlayWindow` and call `resignKeyWindow` on your current window before calling `makeKeyAndVisible`

Comment: thanks I just made it strong reference and it works. However, about the `resignKeyWindow`, the document says that should never invoke this method directly.Therefore, I dont feel safe when calling it.

Comment: Ok, I added that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try keeping a strong reference to the `StatusBarOverlayWindow`, without that the variable will go out of scope after the `addViewOnTop:` method is complete. A property will work well here.

Example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) StatusBarOverlayWindow *overlayWindow;

@end
```

Then in your method:

```
- (IBAction)addViewOnTop:(id)sender {
    self.overlayWindow = [[ACStatusBarOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    overlay.hidden = NO;
    [overlay makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: please see my answer abobe

Comment: I think we just use either overlay.hidden = NO or `overlay makeKeyAndVisible`.